# VisibleDeprecationWarning when creating random array of size 2e5

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I defined var1, var2 as the following arrays:

```
N = 2e5
var1 = np.array(50 * np.random.normal(size=N) + 0.1)
var2 = np.array(0.01 * np.random.normal(size=N) - 300)
```

Upon running these 3 statements in python I get the following two warnings:

> `__main__:7:` VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future
>
> `__main__:8:` VisibleDeprecationWarning: using a non-integer number instead of an integer will result in an error in the future

How do I correct this?

Comment: `N = int(2e5)`?

Comment: Did you intend for `N` to be an integer? `e` notation always makes a float.

Comment: Yes! N is intended to be integer. May be I write N=20000, etc ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `size` must be an integer. You used `N=2e5` but that's a float, you can instead just use `2 * 10**5`:

```
>>> type(2e5)
float

>>> type(2*10**5)
int
```

Or otherwise convert the value to an integer.

Comment: Compared to an `int` call, this has the advantage of not losing precision when the number isn't quite representable as a float.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use floats or double as indexes, convert the result into an Int:

```
import numpy as np

N = int(2e5)
var1 = np.array(50*np.random.normal(size=N) + 0.1)
var2 = np.array(0.01*np.random.normal(size=N) - 300)
```